# Send email via ajax working but not entering .done function in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, email, codeigniter-3

I'm sending emails using ajax calls and everything works fine, the emails are being sent with no problems. But the ajax call finish without execute the .done function...it's executing the .fail function but I can't understand why !! if it's working absolutely normal why execute .fail function ? Help me pls here is my code:

AJAX

```
$('#send_mail').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
  url: baseurl+'email/send',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: $(this).serialize()
})
.done(function(data){
  alert("que wea");
})
.fail(function(data){
  alert("chango");
});
});

});
```

CONTROLLER

```
if( $this->input->is_ajax_request()){

        $captcha_answer = $this->input->post('g-recaptcha-response');

      $result = $this->validar($captcha_answer);

      if ($result == 1) {
            $mail = $this->input->post('contact_mail');
            $name = $this->input->post('contact_name');
            $msg = $this->input->post('contact_message');


            $config = array(

            'protocol' => 'esmtp',
            'smtp_host'=> 'mail.novaderma.cl',
            'smtp_port'=> 26,
            'smtp_user'=> 'contacto@novaderma.cl',
            'smtp_pass'=> '******',
            'mailtype'=>  'html',
            'charset'=>   'utf-8',
            'newline' =>  '\r\n',
            'crlf'   => '\n'
           );

           $this->email->initialize($config);

           $this->email->from($mail);
           $this->email->to('contacto@novaderma.cl');
           $this->email->subject('IMPORTANTE CORREO CONTACTO');
           $this->email->message('<h2>PÁGINA NOVADERMA</h2>
                            <hr><br>
                            <br>
                            <p>'.$msg.'</p>
           ');

           if ($this->email->send()) {
             echo json_encode( array('success' => 1));
           }
                         else {
                             echo json_encode( array('success' => 0));
                         }
    /*echo $this->email->print_debugger();*/
    }
    else {

    }

   }
```